# Dynamics ax menu items

Tags: menuitem, axapta

As we know Menu Item is of three type (Display,Action & Output). In action type we we write classes which runs in background. Action type menu item is attached to a form but in the drop down the menu item is not appearing, what could be the problem? Is there any property which sets action menu-item to show or not?

Please note that it is a scenario based question. I don't have any code for this to share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could be several things.

First of all, are you testing with a user having System Administrator role? If not, security will apply. Then, if your menu item isn't allowed in one of your roles (menu item in a privilege which is in a duty which is in a role you have), you can't see it.

The other common issue is form personalization. So, in the contextual menu over your form, choose personalize and with buttons on top right, restore the form. You will have to close and reopen the form then.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for ans. Can you please make clear you point "menu item in a privilege which is in a duty which is in a role you have". Is it 'which is' or 'which is NOT'?

Comment: These are AX 2012 concepts, the AX 2009 term is Security key. Which version do you use?

Comment: Yes, I use the same AX 2012.

Comment: AX 2012 role base security is:
 
- user (or user group) has role(s) define on a scope (all LEs, list of LEs, OU, etc...)
- a role is a set of duties,
- a duty is an activity the user can do (i.e. "Update gift card information"), it is also a set of privileges
- a privilege is a set of menu items and permissions.

All of those are AOT objects. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731787.aspx for more information.

So if your user is sysadmin, no issues. If not, he has to have a role which will allow access to the menu item through the chain (role-duty-priviliege- menu item).